# My query not showing desired results and omitting values for unknown circumstances

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT  users.id,
    EXTRACT(YEAR 
            FROM AGE(users.dob)) AS Age, 
    users.gender,  
    countries.name AS Country,
    app.name AS App 

    FROM users
        LEFT OUTER JOIN app_user_profile
            ON users.id = app_user_profile.users_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN app
            ON app_user_profile.app_id = app.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cities
            ON app.id = cities.country_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN countries
            ON cities.country_id = countries.country_id
    
ORDER BY users.id, Country;
```

The code above is showing following results.

[image: OUTPUT]

Now here, there are values in countries, but they are omitted for unidentifiable reasons.

For reference, I am attaching an image of database too.
[image: DATABASE]

Comment: It's not possible to say exactly where your logic is failing to produce your desired results because we can't see your data, but it's safe to say that either 1) There are `users` records without an `app_user_profile` record 2) there are `app_user_profile` records without an `app` record 3) There are `app` records without `cities` records OR 4) There are `cities` records without `countries` records. To identify, I would change this to a `SELECT *` and see which join is failing (where the columns start going NULL). In other words, one of your Joins/ON clauses is failing.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> LEFT OUTER JOIN cities
>     ON app.id = cities.country_id
> ```

This looks pretty sketchy. It should probably be something like

```
ON ….city_id = cities.id
```

but none of the tables in your schema have `city_id` column, so I wonder what you're trying to join against here.

> ```
> LEFT OUTER JOIN countries
>     ON cities.country_id = countries.country_id
> ```

This is also weird. According to your picture (and the errorless completion of your query), the `countries` table both has an `id` column as well as a `country_id` column - why, what is the difference? `countries.id` should suffice, and be used for matching countries.